# asp.net new page on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to display a new page, in a new window when the user clicks on a button.
Trying to test it out with this but no luck so far:

```
Label1.Text = "<form><input type=button name=print value='Print View' onClick='javascript:window.open('http://mylink','mywindow')'></form>";
```

I think it might be a formatting issue, but just can't see it.
For example this works just fine:

```
<input type=button name=close value='Close' onClick='javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()'>
```

Comment: technicality, but you should be using a literal instead of a label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use:

```
Label1.Text = @"<form><input type=""button"" name=""print"" value=""Print View"" onClick=""javascript:window.open('http://mylink','mywindow')""></form>";
```

If you want to include a variable, you can use:

```
   string url = "http://www.google.com";
   Label1.Text = String.Format(@"<form><input type=""button"" name=""print"" value=""Print View"" onClick=""javascript:window.open('{0}','mywindow')""></form>", url);
```

**However**, make sure the contents of `url` is safe if it came from any user-provided input!  Otherwise, you may be opening up yourself to script injection attacks.

Comment: You don't think the problem is that the OP is setting the value of a **label** to raw HTML?  Does the label control not escape characters?

Comment: @KirkWoll - I don't *believe* the `Label` control escapes by default.  The docs have a security warning and their example code uses HtmlEncode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx

Comment: guess you're right.  Inspecting the code it doesn't appaer to.

Comment: @KirkWoll - You're probably thinking of that *other* ASP.NET control that encodes everything by default, especially when you don't want it to.  The ASP.NET control framework is a fantastic mess of inconsistency.

Comment: Ok I need to throw in a variable in the middle of the url and I think I'm getting the formatting wrong again.       Label1.Text = "<form><input type=button name=print value='Print View' onClick='javascript:window.open(\"http://mylink/printable.asp?TID=\"+queryString+\"&ID=2\",\"mywindow\")'></form>";

Comment: @user1315427 - I've updated my answer.  Feel free to update your code with exactly what you're trying though.

Comment: Is the `queryString‌​` variable on the client or server?

Comment: server. I keep getting error that is undefined but I am sure I'm not concatenating the stirng right since I can see the value is correct if I print it in another label.

Comment: Since you're escaping the quotes around `queryString`, the actual text `queryString` is getting sent down to the client rather than the value of that variable.  Try an approach like what I have above using the `String.Format` method.  Or, change `\"+queryString+\"` to `"+queryString+"`

Comment: the {0} method did the trick. forgotten all about it. thanks.

Comment: one last question somewhat related. is it possible to bring up the print menu as soon as a click on  button name=print above? so basically it launches the url and the print options at the same time

Comment: for example if I add ;window.print() to onClick, it does come up but does not print the newly open window, still the already open one.

Comment: @user1315427 - You would need to call `window.print();` within the HTML of the *new* window you're opening, perhaps when the document loads.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over the new page so that is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please try :

```
Label1.Text = "<form><input type=button name=print value='Print View' onClick='javascript:window.open(\"http://mylink\",\"mywindow\")'></form>";
```